# Joomla 1.5.18 cannot log in to the administration panel

Tags: joomla

I just installed joomfish extenstion for my joomla site, and now i am not able to log in to the administration panel, I have tried to reset the password field manually directly from MySql but it does not seem to be working...

If anyone would suggest me any solution or idea that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the published field to 0 on the last 2 installed plugins - which should be Joomfish's

What version of Joomfish did you install?

Comment: I have just brought to one earlier verzion of my db before installing joomfish, and interesting fact is that still I cannot get logged in in administration panel, I am wondering if joomfish would have made problem why after i brought up my earlier database still not working :s?